# DataTemplate not being applied

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a window in which I want to display dynamic content based on a datatemplate.

The XAML looks roughly like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Report.ControlLibrary.ReportHost"
         xmlns:reports="clr-namespace:Report.ControlLibrary.Reports"
\>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReportTemplate" DataType="{x:Type reports:ReportViewModel}">
        <!-- Markup for DataTemplate goes here -->         
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>   
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">

</ContentControl>
</Window>
```

The DataContext is being set by:

```
var vm = new ReportViewModel();
var report = new ReportHost() { DataContext=vm };          
report.Show();
```

It seems like the DataContext on the Window is set correctly but the DataTemplate is not found as the window just contains the ToString representation of my ViewModel.

Comment: Unless your actual code does in fact not look "roughly like this", then it should work. You do actually use `x:Type` in the `DataType`, right?

Comment: if you set it manually  does it display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By any chance do you have an x:Key defined in your datatemplate.  If so that will cause the content presenter not to use the datatemplate.  It was an issue I had recently.

Comment: Yes that was it!  I had x:Key in addition to DataType and that was conflicting.  I also found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx under the section on DataType.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use ContentControl.ContentTemplate to set the DataTemplate you want to use for the Content. Check out the explanation [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/okoboji/archive/2007/02/12/on-itemtemplate-contenttemplate-datatemplate.aspx)

Comment: The point here is to make it apply automatically via the `DataType` property.